# react-navigation: is this really the only way to access sibling and parent navigators?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So, I have a somewhat complicated nesting of navigators in my app (4 layers), and it is useful to be able to grab data from the params of each.

For instance, I have tabs, within tabs, that are inside a stack navigator. To access params from one of the screens therein I have do this:

`const homeSiblingNavigator = props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().dangerouslyGetParent().getChildNavigation('Home');`

First of all, calling `dangerouslyGetParent()` inspires absolutely no confidence.

Secondly, I feel like there should be a way, if you uniquely name every route, to find route by name.

I'm thinking of writing some weird recursive/loopy route finder. But before I do, I'm curious if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the path of the screen. And to get the parameters of the screen, `getActionForPathAndParams` can be used.

**routing example**

```js
const AuthSwitch = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator({
  AuthLoading:  { screen: AuthLoadingScreen },
  App: {
    screen: AppStack,
    path: '',
  },
  Auth: { screen: AuthStack },
}));

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Friends: {
    screen: FriendsScreen,
    path: 'friends',
  },
});

const FriendsScreen = createStackNavigator({
  Overview: { screen: OverviewScreen },
  Chat: {
    screen: ChatScreen,
    path: 'chat/:user',
  },
});
```

**getActionForPathAndParams Example**

```js
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

const MyApp = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
})
const previousGetActionForPathAndParams = MyApp.router.getActionForPathAndParams;

Object.assign(MyApp.router, {
  getActionForPathAndParams(path, params) {
    if (
      path === 'my/custom/path' &&
      params.magic === 'yes'
    ) {
      // returns a profile navigate action for /my/custom/path?magic=yes
      return NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: 'Profile',
        action: NavigationActions.navigate({
          // This child action will get passed to the child router
          // ProfileScreen.router.getStateForAction to get the child
          // navigation state.
          routeName: 'Friends',
        }),
      });
    }
    return previousGetActionForPathAndParams(path, params);
  },
});
```